# How to make a switch statement wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have made an application that consists of a `datePicker` and a `comboBox`. The `comboBox` has a list of numbers ranging from 0 through to 5. When the user selects "1" using the `comboBox` my `datePicker` "`dpkClaim1`" will be enabled but the rest of my `datePickers` will be disabled. If the user selects 2 both `dpkClaim1` and `dpkClaim2` will be enabled if the user selects 3 `dpkClaim1` `dpkClaim2` `dpkClaim3` will be enabled and so on. I'm wondering if I could use a switch instead of a series of if statements to provide cleaner code.

My code is as fallows

xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxNoClaims" SelectionChanged="cbxNoClaims_SelectionChanged" Loaded="cbxNoClaims_Loaded" Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
<DatePicker Name="dpkClaim1"  Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<DatePicker Name="dpkClaim2"  Grid.Row="14" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<DatePicker Name="dpkClaim3"  Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<DatePicker Name="dpkClaim4"  Grid.Row="16" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

xaml.cs

```
private void cbxNoClaims_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... A List.
    List<string> claim = new List<string>();
    claim.Add("0 ");
    claim.Add("1");
    claim.Add("2");
    claim.Add("3");
    claim.Add("4");
    claim.Add("5");


    // ... Get the ComboBox reference.
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    // ... Assign the ItemsSource to the List.
    comboBox.ItemsSource = claim;
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void cbxNoClaims_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cbxNoClaims.SelectedItem.ToString() == "1")
    {
        dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    else
    {
        dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = false;
        dpkClaim2.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    if (cbxNoClaims.SelectedItem.ToString() == "2")
    {
        dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = true;
        dpkClaim2.IsEnabled = true;

    }
    else
    {

        dpkClaim2.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    if (cbxNoClaims.SelectedItem.ToString() == "3")
    {
        dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = true;
        dpkClaim2.IsEnabled = true;
        dpkClaim3.IsEnabled = true;

    }
    else
    {

        dpkClaim3.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    if (cbxNoClaims.SelectedItem.ToString() == "4")
    {
        dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = true;
        dpkClaim2.IsEnabled = true;
        dpkClaim3.IsEnabled = true;
        dpkClaim4.IsEnabled = true;

    }
    else
    {

        dpkClaim4.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the onchanged event of the combobox you want to do something like this:

```
switch (combobox.SelectedItem) {
    case "1":
        datebox1.IsEnabled = true;
        break;
    case "2":
        datebox1.IsEnabled = true;
        datebox2.IsEnabled = true;
        break;
    default:
        //what you want when nothing is selected
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be simplified a lot:

```
cbxNoClaims.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 6);
```

```
var count = (int)cbxNoClaims.SelectedItem;
dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = count >= 1;
dpkClaim2.IsEnabled = count >= 2;
dpkClaim3.IsEnabled = count >= 3;
dpkClaim4.IsEnabled = count >= 4;
dpkClaim5.IsEnabled = count >= 5;
dpkClaim6.IsEnabled = count >= 6;
```

Though you still should really use [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx) and [data templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. However, you might want to rethink the way you do things in your project (refering to H.B.'s answer).

```
switch(cbxNoClaims.SelectedItem) {
    case "1":
        // code here
        break;
    case "2":
        // also here
        break;
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would not work with concrete instances at all, instead create a list of models based on the selected number, then bind an `ItemsControl` with `ItemTemplate` containing the `ComboBox` to that. This will yield *n* inputs, without the need for disabling anything.